# Satellite retrieval, fix and deploy possible remotely?

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite, reentry, reuse

Is there any satellites that are designed to come back to Earth for repairs or upgrades and then be deployed again? Would there be any benefits to creating a capsule or inflatable heat shield to go on and bring back satellites?

After piggy backing off another payload could heat shields remotely solar sail to debris in slightly different orbits be retrieved for repair or otherwise?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: when this answer was written, the question was phrased as follows (6 revisions have been done to the question at this writing):*

> Is there any satellites that are designed to come back to Earth for
>   repairs and be deployed again? Would there be any benefits to creating
>   a capsule to bring back satellites? or would it just be cheaper to
>   build another?

It is possible and has been done.

One of the design requirements for the space shuttle was the ability to retrieve satellites from orbit.

This was done infrequently, Hobbes gives a list in his answer to this question: [What satellites did the Shuttle retrieve from orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15094/what-satellites-did-the-shuttle-retrieve-from-orbit)

Some satellites were repaired in orbit by the shuttle as well, including the famous Hubble Space Telescope.  See also [Besides HST, JWST and stations, are there any examples of satellites designed for service in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16845/besides-hst-jwst-and-stations-are-there-any-examples-of-satellites-designed-fo/19000#19000)

Comment: As well as whatever the USAF has secretly brought back using the X-37.

Comment: @DrSheldon i'm extremely interested in that as an answer!

Comment: X-37 operations are kept secret, we don't know anything about its payloads.

Comment: It's worth noting that the question has been edited considerably since this answer was written.